# Data not showing, error: <!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "" }-->

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Compiler is not giving any error but data is not being shown on the front-end. And the error I get is `<!--bindings={   "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "" }-->`

Here is my component TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PostsService } from 'src/app/services/posts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-category',
  templateUrl: './single-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-category.component.css']
})
export class SingleCategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  postsArray: Array<object> = []; 
  categoryObj: any;

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private postService: PostsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe (val => {
      console.log (val);
      this.categoryObj = val;
      this.postService.loadCategoryPosts(val['id']).subscribe(post => {
        this.postsArray = post; 
        
      })

    })
  }

}
```

And here is the HTML, I am using NGFOR directive:

```
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor = "let post of postsArray">
            <app-post-card [postData] = "post"></app-post-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to pass blog posts in categories, so I naturally assumed it should be an Array. The console log shows the ids of the posts captured but they are not shown on the front end.

EDIT:

This is my loadCategoryPosts method:

```
  loadCategoryPosts ( categoryId: any ) {
        return this.afs.collection('posts', ref => ref.where('category.categoryId', '==', categoryId).limit(4)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.doc.data(); 
              const id = a.payload.doc.id; 
              return { id, data }
    
            })
          })
        )
    
      }
```

Comment: Does your `his.postService.loadCategoryPosts` actually return an array ?

Comment: When I console log it, it does, maybe `(val['id'])` is problematic?